# CSS loader and Extract Text Plugin Use Case Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, extract-text-plugin

I understand that CSS-loader just modularizes your CSS so that if you import `style.css` in your `foo.js`, whenever `foo.js` gets run, it has a reference to `style.css` such that your elements created in `foo.js` can then have the hashed classNames of `style.css`. Then style loader is usually used to put`style.css` into a `<style>` tag on your html so that the styles get applied.

I'm not sure what the point of Extract Text Plugin. Is it so that you don't need Style Loader and then you can extract all your css into a file and then link to it yourself by manually putting in the name in your html?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin):

> It moves all the required *.css modules in entry chunks into a separate CSS file. So your styles are no longer inlined into the JS bundle, but in a separate CSS file (styles.css). If your total stylesheet volume is big, it will be faster because the CSS bundle is loaded in parallel to the JS bundle.